# Intemporal budget by lagrange

Tags: calculus, economics, utility, euler-lagrange-equation

Assume that a representative agent lives forever and receives an endowment, denoted yt, in each period. The entire endowment sequence is known
with certainty on date 0. The representative agent discounts future utility at
rate $\beta$ and has a period utility function given by
$u(c_{t}) = (c_{t})^{1-\sigma}/(1-\sigma)  $

(d)write the intertemporal budget constraint of the representative
agent by aggregating the flow budget constraints.
Write down the Lagrangian using the constraint in (d). How many
Lagrange multipliers are there? Find the first order conditions and write down
the Euler equation.

I have found the equation 
$ L = \beta^tU(c_{t}) + (\lambda)_{t}(1/(1+r)^t)(c_{t}-y_{t}) $

then I have found the equation by taking derivative of L with respect to $c_{t}$ and $c_{t+1}$ but since there are no savings(b) I could not take derivative of L with respect to b so cannot find the ratio of lamdas :
$ \frac{U^{'}(c_{t})}{U^{'}(c_{t+1})\beta} = \frac{(\lambda)_{t}}{(\lambda)_{t+1}(r+1)}$

Comment: `\lambda` and `\sigma` in $\LaTeX$ give $\lambda$ and $\sigma$

Comment: thank you do you have any idea about problem @Henry

Comment: @Pumpkin In the first equation a closing bracket is missing. Are the two $\sigma$-signs correct in the first equation ? What is the correct term ? You should also explain the meanings of $\lambda$ and $\sigma$.

Comment: $\lambda$ is lagrange multiplier other has no importance just a parameter @calculus

Comment: @Pumpkin And $\sigma$ ?

Comment: it is just a parameter for utility func. does not affect the solution

Comment: You're not supplying all the information. What exactly is the flow budget constraint for this problem? There is no savings? Then why would the agent not simply consume his endowment every period?

Comment: With savings, you would guess that the Euler equation looks like the usual trade-off between marginal utilities $U'(c_t) = \beta (1+r) U'(c_{t+1})$.

Comment: @Michael how did you find $\frac{(\lambda)_{t}}{(\lambda)_{t+1} = 1 $ ?

Answer (score -1):

The lagrange-function should be look like this:

$\mathcal L=\sum_{t=0}^{n} \left( \beta ^t\cdot \frac{1}{1-\sigma}\cdot c_t^{1-\sigma}+ \lambda_t \left(  \frac{y_t}{(1+r)^t}- \frac{c_t}{(1+r)^t} \right) \right) $

$ y_t- c_t  =0\Rightarrow \text{No savings in period t}$

First order condition:

$\frac{d L}{d c_t}=\beta ^t\cdot \frac{1}{1-\sigma} \cdot (1-\sigma) c_t^{1-\sigma}-\frac{\lambda _t}{(1+r)^t}=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_t =\beta ^t\cdot \frac{(1+r)^t}{1-\sigma} \cdot (1-\sigma) c_t^{1-\sigma} \quad (1) $

$\frac{d L}{d c_{t+1}}=\beta ^{t+1}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\sigma} \cdot (1-\sigma) c_{t+1}^{1-\sigma}-\frac{\lambda _{t+1}}{(1+r)^{t+1}}=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_{t+1} =\beta ^{t+1}\cdot \frac{(1+r)^{t+1}}{1-\sigma} \cdot (1-\sigma) c_{t+1}^{1-\sigma} \quad (2) $

Dividing (2) by (1) gives $\frac{\lambda _{t+1} }{\lambda _{t}}=\beta \cdot (1+r) \frac{c_{t+1}^{1-\sigma}}{c_{t}^{1-\sigma}}$

It is the same as $\frac{\lambda _{t+1} }{\lambda _{t}}=\beta \cdot (1+r) \frac{U'(c_{t+1})}{U'(c_{t})}$

My relation is a little bit different from yours.

Comment: If agent is infinitely lived, why is your $n$ finite? If $y_t = c_t$ and $y_t$ is exogenous, what are you solving for?

Comment: n can go to infinity. The second point is a good point. But I haven`t seen other way to get the relation. If you have a better way, then it would be helpful to provide an answer.

Comment: $n$ can go to infinity? Really?

Comment: Sure, if the representative agent lives forever.